# Yii2 How to create models dynamically and specify relationship among them?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am creating tables on the fly. If I created the tables **Schools** and **Classes**. How can I create the models for them and specify relationships among them.

I searched but did not get anything on this topic. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: May be this post help for you https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/ar-single-table-inheritance.md

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can figure out is to use "global variables" for tables - e.g. in Yii::$app->params['ar_tables'] and redefine them dynamically:

In config:

```
[
    ....
    'params' => [
         'ar_tables' => [
             'Parent' => 'parent',
             'Child' => 'table2' 
         ]
    ]
    ....
]
```

Parent class:

```
class Parent extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return Yii::$app->params['ar_tables']['Parent'];
    }


    public function getChildren
    {
        return self::hasMany(Child::className(), ['parent_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
class Child extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return Yii::$app->params['ar_tables']['Child'];
    }


    public function getParent
    {
        return self::hasOne(Parent::className(), ['id' => 'parent_id']);
    }   
}
```

After that you can dynamically change Yii::$app->params['ar_tables'] values for getting what you want. I have already tried this. And didn't like :)